# Blind Harry Potter story where Snape is sent to retrieve Harry from the Dursleys

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a story I read once. It's a *Harry Potter* fanfic where Snape has to retrieve Harry from the Dursleys because he didn't arrive on the train. I *think* it's after 5th year, but I'm not sure.

Anyway Snape gets there and Harry is blind, blinded over the summer by his uncle. I remember Snape asking Harry something about missing the train and Harry replying "my uncle won" and I think that's when Snape finds out he is blind. Harry had been sitting in his window seat petting his owl, not looking at Snape.

Comment: [This link](https://m.fanfiction.net/community/blind-harry/70876/) contains a group of blind Harry fanfics. It might help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*To See A Falling Star* by Lady FoxFire, [published on fanfiction.net](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/784754/1/To-See-A-Falling-Star) from 2002 to 2009. Warning: it's rated for violence and sexual content.

> When Vernon's abuse goes to far, will Harry be able too *[sic]* live with the effects?

More precisely... (All following quotes from the first chapter)

**Snape has to retrieve Harry from the Dursley's because he didn't arrive on the train.**

> The door only opened a few inches before the security chain stopped it. A woman pressed her face against the narrow opening, the door hiding her features from view. She studied the tall pale man on her porch and swallowed nervously before she found her voice. "Yes? Can I help you?" her voice trembled.
>
> "Is this the Dursley's residence?" the mysterious man asked in a deep, rich voice.
>
> "Yes." The woman replied timidly. "But my husband is away right now, perhaps if you try at his office in the morning…" she said as she tried to shut the door.
>
> The man thrust his boot in between the door and it's jam, leaning his weight against the door. "I'm not here to see your husband, Mrs. Dursley. I'm here about the Potter child."
>
> "Harry?" The woman squeaked with panic in her eyes. "What... what do you want with him?" Her voice trembled with fear.
>
> **"I'm Professor Snape, Potter's potions teacher at Hogwarts. When he didn't arrive at the school, I was sent to retrieve the child," he explained.**

**I remember Snape asking Harry something about missing the train and Harry replying "my uncle won".**

> Finally he noticed Potter sitting at his window, his back toward the door watching the moon slowly rise into the sky. His white owl Hedwig sat on the windowsill next to him as the boy stroked her soft feathers. Hedwig ruffled her feathers when she saw Snape in the doorway.
>
> "Go away," Harry said in a dejected voice as he watched Snape's reflection in the windowpane.
>
> "Hardly. I've been sent to retrieve you, Potter," Snape said snidely. "I'm surprised at you. I didn't even think you could mess up such a simple thing as catching the Hogwarts Express." [...]
>
> "No," Harry replied softly as he continued to watch Snape's reflection, refusing to turn around and face the man. **"There's no point in me ever returning Hogwarts. My uncle won."**

**That's when Snape finds out he is blind.**

> "Potter, face me when I'm taking to you."
>
> Snape marched over to Harry, grabbed the boy by his shirt and whirled him around, preparing to yell in his face. "Harry!" His voice trembled sickly as he looked into the boy's eyes.
>
> Where once his eyes were a brilliant green, they were now dull and cloudy, like a frosted windowpane on a wintry day. **Harry snarled as he stared up unseeingly at Snape, "As you can see, professor, I can't."**

---

Found with the Google query `harry potter fanfiction "* uncle won" "window" -"uncle won't"`.

Comment: How did Harry "watch[ed] Snape's reflection in the windowpane" if he was blind?

Comment: @Alex don't ask me. Fanfiction logic.

Comment: @Jenayah - I think it's meant to show Snape's point of view.

Comment: @Adamant could be. But in all bad faith I'm choosing to assume fanfiction logic :)

Comment: @Alex you just made me laugh out loud, I needed that <3 kudos to you for actually reading through the full answer.

Comment: @Sensoray Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for finding the fanfiction! I know I’m rather late in replying, I’m sorry.

Comment: @LocoBriar no worries, enjoy the re-read :)